# Using groupBy on nested collection in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I am having a syntax issue I guess. i am trying to group a collection that is nested in another. The collections have been retrieving using 'with' as they have a relationship. My grouBy code is throwing an error that says i am passing in an object.

> strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

What is the issue here?

```
$clientAndAppointments = Client::where('status', 1)->orderby('first_name', 'asc')
    ->with(['appointments' => function ($query)  use ($weekStart, $weekEnd) {
         $query->whereBetween('starts_at', [$weekStart, $weekEnd])->groupBy(function($day) {
            return Carbon::parse($day->starts_at, 'Europe/London')->format('l');
        });            
    }, 'appointments.employees.user'])->with('careType')->get();
```

Comment: Where is the function `strtolower()` or if i am not wrong its the same function body itself

Comment: I think it may be the laravel groupBy implementation that has ststolower(). I dont explicitly call it.

Comment: you need to see the parameter which this implicit function `strtolower()` called by is receiving is the $day a string its not as per the error you are receiving

Comment: $day shouldn't be the problem. I return a string from the function which should then be used by groupBy.